# Use a ColorStateList with a checkable option menu item and state_checked

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-optionsmenu

My options menu is populated with items such as:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_bus"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:checked="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_bus"
    android:title="@string/bus"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

Here's my `onOptionsItemsSelected`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());

    Log.d("test", "Item " + item + " is now checked: " + item.isChecked());
    ColorStateList colorStateList = getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.options_menu_colors);
    Drawable d = DrawableCompat.wrap(item.getIcon());
    DrawableCompat.setTintList(d, colorStateList);
    item.setIcon(d);

    return true;
}
```

As you can see my goal is to have widget tinting in older versions of android, using the feature of the support libraries v22.1.

The color is defined as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/accent" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/secondary_text"/>
</selector>
```

However the `state_checked` isn't working with checkbox menu items!

Here's the log of icon presses:

```
D/test    (11529): Item Bus is checked: false
D/test    (11529): Item Bus is checked: true
D/test    (11529): Item Bus is checked: false
D/test    (11529): Item Bus is checked: true
```

I tried to switch the selector to `state_pressed`: this one works! While touching the menu item, the color changes!

So why can't the `ColorStateList` work with the `state_checked` on option menu items?

PS: using this works:

```
int colorId = item.isChecked() ? R.color.accent : R.color.secondary_text;
int color = getResources().getColor(colorId);
DrawableCompat.setTint(d, color);
```

But obviously I would've wanted something more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [Using checkable menu items](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#checkable), 
you have to manually indicate the checked state, for e.g.

```
if(item.isCheckable()) {
    int[] state = {item.isChecked() ? android.R.attr.state_checked : android.R.attr.state_empty};
    item.getIcon().setState(state);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It likely doesn't work because your `Drawable` doesn't implement the `Checkable` interface - the `MenuItem` is what's checked.